# AngularJS - include View for a module

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and working on my first application right now.
I've coded a Template into my index.html, but want to put die view for each model in a seperate html file. I tried some options, ng-include and so on, but nothing works. My views are in app/views.

index.html:

`<div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="LeftMenuCtrl"></div> // This Menu for example should be on every single page/route.
        <div ng-view=""></div> // Views for routes are working
</div>`

How can I solve this?

Comment: please show your write ng-include

Comment: I've tried ng-include="views/leftMenu.html" and ng-include="'views/leftMenu.html'" (saw somewhere at stackoverflow)

Comment: Can you provide the code for your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD `'` in inside your `ng-include="views/leftMenu.html"`

For Example

```
<div ng-include="'views/leftMenu.html'" />
```

Comment: I've also tried this, but it did not work, thought it's the right answer. I've figured out, that bower did not include a JS file in my index.html (forgot about "install --save ..."), thats why it did not work. Even the console didn't show any errors. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
ng-include="'app/views/leftMenu.html'"
```

If that doesn't work double check the path

Comment: Should be within inner quotes: `"'app/views/leftMenu.html'"`